# PHP menu Active "Here" Link

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, menu, navbar, menuitem

I want to put my menu in a separate PHP file so when I need to edit it, I only have to edit it once. The problem starts when I want to highlight the active page. Can someone help me to fix it?

```
<?php $currentPage = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); ?>
```

Toggle navigation

```
                        <li><a href="index.php" <?php if ($currentPage == 'index.php') { echo 'id="here"'; }?>><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.php" <?php if ($currentPage == 'about.php') { echo 'id="here"'; }?>><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span> About us</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> Services <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">  
                                <li><a href="services1.php" <?php if ($currentPage == 'services1.php') { echo 'id="here"'; }?>><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Drivers services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="services2.php" <?php if ($currentPage == 'services2.php') { echo 'id="here"'; }?>><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Shop services</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="application.php"<?php if ($currentPage == 'application.php') { echo 'id="here"'; }?>><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> On-line Application</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.php" <?php if ($currentPage == 'contact.php') { echo 'id="here"'; }?>><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Contact us</a></li>

                    </ul>

                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div><!-- navbar -->
```

Comment: fix what? you haven't told us the problem

Comment: What happens if you put it in a separate file? `basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])` should still return the script name you are looking for.

Comment: @nogad It doesn't highlight the active page as it does when I hover the menu.

Comment: @jrn I tried but doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: How do you know which site to render? Are you passing it as a variable in the URL like `http://www.example.com/index.php?view=about`?

Comment: @jrn I didn't did anything like that. I'm newbie in PHP also.

Comment: Maybe elaborate in your question a little bit on how you split up the files? How do you include he menu in about.php etc...

Comment: @jrn Thank you so much for doing your best to help me. My pages have include files: title.php, header.php, menu.php, page_content.php, back_top.php, footer.php, social.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution to my question adding this css in styles file:

```css
/* The here ID identifies the current page and applies a white color to the text and a black background as a visual indicator. */

a#here {
    background-color: #000 !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}
```

Plus call the menu in each page with following code:

```
<div> <?php 
               $file ='includes/menu.php';
               if (file_exists($file) && is_readable($file))    {
                include($file);
                }   else    {
                    throw new Exception("$file can't be found");
                    }
               include('includes/menu.php');?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

A quick and dirty method to achieving this is in each file put the following:

```
<?php
    include("header.php"); // Insert location of header file here
?>
```

and in your header.php file after creating your head block insert this

```
<?php $active= substr(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']),0, -4); ?> // Page Name
<body <?php echo "class='$active'";?>> // This sets the bodies class to be the page name.
```

finally in style.css use the following code to set the highlighted feature

```
// This is an example for my CSS. Insert your own css selector

// In my css i have this which adds a small orange bar to the bottom of the navigation option. I set the opacity to 0 to not display it.
.header nav ul li a:before 
{
    height: 5px;
    background: #ea5c18;
    opacity: 0;
}
// Then i set .PageName (the bodies class name) and set that specific nav element to have an opacity of 1.
.PageName .header nav ul li:first-child a:before
{
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: dirty is right, when you can just detect the page with a $_SERVER variable,

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that. Edited my answer @nogad

Comment: @NathanLeadill I'm checking it right now and I will keep you posted. I wasn't able to ass the CSS in my post, I'm not sure what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @NathanLeadill Thank you so much for doing your best to help me. I tried  to apply your suggestion to my project but will not work. I'm still looking into it. The menu as I wrote my code shows fine and when you hover it changes color but will not show my active page.